# Angular и p5.js - p5.loadSound is not a function

Tags: angular2, typescript

Использую Angular CLI.

В своем приложении я подключаю библиотеку **[p5.js](https://p5js.org/)** для создания эквлайзера.

Делаю это в файле **.angular-cli.json**:

```
"scripts": [    
  "../node_modules/p5/lib/p5.min.js",   
  "../node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.sound.js",   
  "../node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.dom.js"  
],
```

Затем в компоненте пишу следующий код:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as p5 from 'p5';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.scss']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  play: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const s = (p) => {

      let song;
      let canvas;

      p.preload = () => {
        console.log('preload');
        song = p.loadSound('assets/music/Thunderstruck.mp3');
      }

      p.setup = () => {
        canvas = p.createCanvas(595, 100);
        canvas.parent('equalizer');
        p.background(0);
      }
    }

    let player = new p5(s);

  }

  onPlay() {
    this.play = !this.play;

  }

}
```

Пробую загрузить песню используя **loadSound()**, но JS говорит ***ERROR TypeError: p.loadSound is not a function***

Хорошо, **loadSound()** нельзя применить, но почему когда в консоли браузера я пишу вот это:

```
let song = p5.prototype.loadSound('assets/music/Thunderstruck.mp3');
song.play();
```

все работает([скрин консоли](http://prntscr.com/g1jx40))?

В компоненте я тоже пробовал обратиться к прототипу:

```
song = p.prototype.loadSound('assets/music/Thunderstruck.mp3');
```

Это не работает.

Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: вечная проблема) попробуй в index.html

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо заменить

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';
```

на

```
declare var p5: any;
```

в случае с импортом у нас получается два глобальных объекта p5